Am I Using `ThreadPoolExecutor` correctly?
Okay, i'm kinda lost and afraid of doing it in the wrong way.
some contexts:

Im doing some kinda image processing
Source data are stored separately in disk
each data will be existed as 2D numpy array in the program

more thorough contexts:

let's say i have 100 raw data/images
created a class that take those images in batch(es)

here's the snippet:
class VolumeBatch:
  def __init__(self, ...):

    # shape equal to (batch_size, height, width)
    # the height and width are the image size
    self.container = some_3d_np_array 
  
  def self.__processeor(self, input_from_generator: tuple[int, Any]):
    """all the necessary image procssing goes here""" 
    
    idx, raw_2d_np_array = input_from_generator
    ...
    results = do_the_image_processing(raw_2d_np_array)
    
    return a_dictionary # {"idx": idx, "results": results}

  def connect_internally(self, field_instance: FieldPredLine, max_workers: int = 4) -> None:
    """Process a single batch i.e. calculating connected component for a single batch"""
    # `field_instance` in map(...) below
    # is another interface with __getitem__ 
    generator = list(zip(
        list(self.batch_size),
        map(lambda i: field_instance[i], list(self.batch_size)),
    ))
    
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as executor:
      for result in tqdm( executor.map(self.__processeor, generator), ...):
        idx = result.pop("idx")
        # update the 3d_numpy_array that acts as the container
        # relying on the `idx` to store the result in right position
        self.container[idx, :, :] = result.pop( "results" )


In the main program i created something like these:

def process_several_batches(batch_size: int) -> list[VolumeBatch]:
  # instantiation of `VolumeBatch` before
  batches: list[VolumeBatch] = [
        VolumeBatch(...) for _, range_xl in ranges.items()
    ]

  # local_workers <<< MAX_WORKERS
  def initiate(batch, field, local_workers): 
     """here i call the method that runs another ThreadPoolExecutor"""
     batch.connect_internally(field, max_workers=local_workers)
     return None

  with tqdm(...) as pbar:
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=MAX_WORKERS) as executor:
      for _ in executor.map(initiate, batches, field, workers):
        pbar.update(1.0)
  return batches



I really appreciate any helps , may you all will always have an infinite sigma rizz next year!, thank you!
Edit (addition)
There are no errors nor weird things going on with the result i.e. the populated 3d_numpy_array for each batch... but still I'm very not sure about the way i was doing it.
here's the result
   Processing batch(es)...:   0%|                                              | 0/9 [00:00<?, ?it/s]

        || Loading Data...:   0%|                         | 0/50 [00:00<?, ?it/s]

        || Loading Data...:   0%|                         | 0/50 [00:00<?, ?it/s]

        || Loading Data...:   0%|                         | 0/50 [00:00<?, ?it/s]

        || Loading Data...:   0%|                         | 0/50 [00:00<?, ?it/s]

        || Loading Data...:   0%|                         | 0/50 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
        || Loading Data...:   2%|▎                | 1/50 [00:05<04:17,  5.25s/it]
        || Loading Data...:   0%|                         | 0/50 [00:00<?, ?it/s]

        || Loading Data...:   2%|▎                | 1/50 [00:05<04:41,  5.75s/it]
        || Loading Data...:   4%|▋                | 2/50 [00:06<02:24,  3.00s/it]
        || Loading Data...:   0%|                         | 0/50 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
        || Loading Data...:   2%|▎                | 1/50 [00:06<05:20,  6.54s/it]
        || Loading Data...:   0%|                         | 0/50 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
        || Loading Data...:   4%|▋                | 2/50 [00:06<02:13,  2.77s/it]

        || Loading Data...:   2%|▎                | 1/50 [00:06<05:09,  6.31s/it]

        || Loading Data...:   2%|▎                | 1/50 [00:06<05:37,  6.89s/it]

        || Loading Data...:   4%|▋                | 2/50 [00:06<02:18,  2.89s/it]
        || Loading Data...:   2%|▎                | 1/50 [00:07<06:10,  7.56s/it]
        || Loading Data...:   4%|▋                | 2/50 [00:07<02:32,  3.18s/it]
        || Loading Data...:   2%|▎                | 1/50 [00:07<06:03,  7.41s/it]
        || Loading Data...:   8%|█▎               | 4/50 [00:11<01:58,  2.57s/it]
        || Loading Data...:  10%|█▋               | 5/50 [00:10<01:16,  1.70s/it]

.....

Processing batch(es)...:  44%|████████████████                    | 4.0/9 [01:57<01:30, 18.18s/it]
        Processing batch(es)...:  67%|████████████████████████            | 6.0/9 [01:58<00:27,  9.00s/it]
        Processing batch(es)...: 100%|████████████████████████████████████| 9.0/9 [01:58<00:00, 13.22s/it]

=================================================================

Finisheh in 251.2347 seconds

=================================================================


